# What is causing a SIGSEGV using blocks?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I have the following code.  I get a SIGSEGV occasionally.  I have a feeling I'm missing something regarding memory management using blocks.  Is it safe to pass the replacedUrls, which is autoreleased to this block?  What about modifying the instance variable formattedText?

```
    NSMutableSet* replacedUrls = [[[NSMutableSet alloc] init] autorelease];

    NSError *error = nil; 
    NSDataDetector *detector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:
                                (NSTextCheckingTypeLink | NSTextCheckingTypePhoneNumber)
                                                               error:&error];
    if (error) {
        return;
    }

    [detector enumerateMatchesInString:self.formattedText 
              options:0 
              range:NSMakeRange(0, [self.formattedText length]) 
              usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop) {

            @try  {
                if (result.resultType == NSTextCheckingTypePhoneNumber) {

                    if (!result.phoneNumber) {
                        // not sure if this is possible
                        return;
                    }

                    self.formattedText = [self.formattedText stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:result.phoneNumber
                                                                                       withString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<a href=\"tel://%@\">%@</a>", result.phoneNumber, result.phoneNumber]];
                }
                else if (result.resultType == NSTextCheckingTypeLink) {

                    if (!result.URL) {
                        // not sure if this is possible
                        return;
                    }

                    NSString* fullUrl = [result.URL absoluteString];

                    if (!fullUrl) {
                        return; 
                    }

                    if ([replacedUrls containsObject:fullUrl]) {
                        return; 
                    }

                    // not sure if this is possible
                    if ([result.URL host] && [result.URL path]) {
                        NSString* urlWithNoScheme = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", [result.URL host], [result.URL path]];

                        // replace all http://www.google.com to www.google.com
                        self.formattedText = [self.formattedText stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:fullUrl
                                                                                           withString:urlWithNoScheme];

                        // replace all www.google.com with http://www.google.com
                        NSString* replaceText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<a href=\"%@\">%@</a>", fullUrl, fullUrl];
                        self.formattedText = [self.formattedText stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:urlWithNoScheme
                                                                                           withString:replaceText];

                        [replacedUrls addObject:fullUrl];
                    }
                }
            }
            @catch (NSException* ignore) {
                // ignore any issues
            }
        }];
```

Comment: After some reading, I'm definitely seeing where I would be creating a retain cycle since self would be retained.  Still not sure how that would create the actual issue, though.

Comment: the dodgiest line is 'if(error){return;} but i'm not sure how that causes your problem either (your code recovers gracefully if you return at this point, right?). Retaining self doesn't necessarily cause a retain cycle, and a retain cycle wouldn't cause a SIGSEGV;

Comment: Yeah, that line is strange.  I'm not even sure it's necessary.  I think I added it as a sanity check.  It was getting a SIGSEGV before we added that line.  Most of those if statements were added because the crash report just pointed to the general block and not a specific line.  Kind of annoying to track down the issue.  Is it safe to modify the formattedText in this?

Comment: To your question about returning gracefully, it does return fine.  
All we're doing is replacing the urls with the properly escaped urls, so they appear in the control correctly.  There may be a better implementation; odd thing is I can't recreate for the life of me although I'm getting reports.  Either that or this is red herring.  Either way thanks for the help.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the issue you are experiencing is one related to memory management. You begin by searching through the string `self.formattedText`. This means that, while this search takes place, your `NSDataDetector` instance probably needs to access the string to read characters, etc. This works all fine and nice, as long as `self.formattedText` doesn't get deallocated. Usually, even for block methods like this, it is the caller's responsibility to retain the arguments until the end of the function call.

When, inside of your match found block, you change the value of `self.formattedText`, the old value is automatically released (assuming that this is a `retain` property). I am not aware of caching that NSDataDetector might do, or issues pertaining to autorelease pools, etc., but I am pretty certain that this could cause an issue.

**my suggestion is that you pass** `[NSString stringWithString:self.formattedText]` as the `enumerateMatchesInString:` argument, rather than the plain `self.formattedText`. This way, you pass the NSDataDetector an instance that won't be released until the autorelease pool is drained.

Comment: I haven't fully tested this, but I think your answer is worthy.  :)